# How to push a {key: value} object in my MongoDB array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update my User objects by pushing a post into the array I created for it. I have tried doing this a couple different ways but so far nothing has worked or updated an user object. I'm new to MongoDB but so far I really like it and am excited to use it more. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```js
//Home page
router.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('home', {user_mv: req.user}));

//Create topic page
router.get('/create-topic', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('create-topic', {user_mv: req.user}));

//Post handle
router.post('/create-topic', (req, res) => {
     User.update( {_id: req.body.user_id},
        {
            $push: {
                postArr: {
                    title: req.body.title,
                    category: req.body.category,
                    vista: req.body.vista,
                    description: req.body.description
                }
            }   
        });
    res.send(req.body.user_id);      
});
```

```css
const DBmusevistaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    postArr: [
        {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            category: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            vista: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" value="<%= user_mv._id %>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Update` syntax is fine.

`req.body.user_id` comes as string (assuming you don't use any specific middleware to re-cast it).

All you have to do is [cast](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) is to an `ObjectId` type. like so:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
```

And then:

```
{_id: new ObjectId(req.body.user_id)}
```

EDIT:

Try and wait on the promise return from `update`, it should still work without waiting for it but without seeing the entire code I can't be sure.

Do this:

```
//Post handle
router.post('/create-topic', async (req, res) => {
     let updateResult = await User.update( {_id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)},
        {
            $push: {
                postArr: {
                    title: req.body.title,
                    category: req.body.category,
                    vista: req.body.vista,
                    description: req.body.description
                }
            }   
        });
    res.send(req.body.user_id);      
});
```

Also I see you're using mongoose so you instead of installing Mongo's API you can use:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

And then:

```
{_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)}
```

Comment: I added var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectId and then _id: new ObjectID(req.body.user_id) but it is not updating. It really helps to know that I have to pass the id and ObjectId for it to work. I also don't get any errors, the res send works.

Comment: Also without your suggested changes the user_id send sent the id w/o quotations and sending your changes in the res.send wrapped the id in double quotes.

Comment: I didn't understand the second comment, but the fact that theres no errors is good progress, next you should make sure the received id does match a document in the collection.

Comment: The id does match the user res. send(req.body.user) sends 5e248598f8cf6520084b6060 and res.send(new ObjectID(req.body.user_id) sends "5e248598f8cf6520084b6060".

Comment: I also installed the mongodb api which I didn't have before and I still cannot get it to update.

Comment: I added an EDIT to my answer with one more thing to try, whats the value of `updateResult`?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I'm gonna study up what is going on there and see what I can understand from it to see how I can use it in the future.

Comment: Glad i could help.